# Extracting specific psuedo tag inside href element using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I have an anchor tag as follows:

```
<a class="gsc_a_at" href= "/citations?view_op=view_citation&amp;hl=en&amp;user=11JgipcAAAAJ&amp;pagesize=100&amp;citation_for_view=11JgipcAAAAJ:j3f4tGmQtD8C">'''
```

I want to extract the content after the `citation_for_view` using `beautifulSoup`. How can I do it without `regular expressions`.

Below is what I tried.

input_data = ''' '''

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(input_data)

for href_tags in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
    print href_tags['href']
```

This outputs:

```
/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=11JgipcAAAAJ&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=11JgipcAAAAJ:j3f4tGmQtD8C
```

How can I extract the content of `citation_for_view` which is within `href` and output just `11JgipcAAAAJ:j3f4tGmQtD8C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `urlparse`

```
>>> import urlparse

>>> url = '/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=11JgipcAAAAJ&pagesize=100&citation_for_view=11JgipcAAAAJ:j3f4tGmQtD8C'
>>> vals = urlparse.parse_qs(url)
>>> print vals.get('citation_for_view')
['11JgipcAAAAJ:j3f4tGmQtD8C']
```